# Algebra with element having empty spectrum?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

The definition of the spectrum makes sense for any algebra. I guess we can go to the unitization to make sense of it even non-unital algebras. Recalling the well-known fact that for normed algebras, the spectrum of each element is always non-empty, I was wondering if there are examples of algebras having an element with empty spectrum.

Maybe one might have some examples in mind where we actually have a topology on the algebra.

Due to the useful comments, I make my setting more precise. I only consider complex algebras and define the spectrum as $$\sigma(x) := \{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}: \lambda 1 - x \text{ not invertible}\}.$$

Comment: just remind us of def of spectrum in an algebra( especially if it is far from being a subdirect product of matrix algebras)

Comment: Didn't you mean "a banach algebra", not  just "normed"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\mathbb C(x)$ - the field of rational functions in one variable over $\mathbb C$. The elements of the algebra are of the form $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)},$ where $p,q\in\mathbb C[x]$ are polynomials with $GCD(p,q)=1$. Then the $(x-\lambda)$ is invertible for every $\lambda \in \mathbb C$. Thus $\sigma(x)$ is empty.

Comment: What is my algebra then again?

Comment: $\mathbb C(x)$ - it has addition and multiplication.

Comment: Can you make this algebra a bit more precise, what are it's elements?

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: What is $x$ again? It seems you have fixed it before defining $\mathbb{C}(x)$.

Comment: $x$ is an element of the algebra $\mathbb C(x)$. Namely, the function $x\mapsto x$.

Comment: What is the domain and image of $x$ as a function then? Sorry I might be very stupid here but I really want to understand that.

Comment: $x$ is the identity function $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$.

Comment: The algebra $\mathbb C(x)$ is the field of fractions over the ring $\mathbb C[x]$. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions